# C# PerformClick method in invisible form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am stuck on using a `PerformClick` method. I have a main form which is called `mymainform`, and I have some subforms. When loading main form, I am creating subforms and hide them with Form Visibility and access some elements on subforms.

My problem is clicking a button on subform1 from MainForm. I have written the below code and it didn't work. Normally `DayModeButton` changes the boolen; `isDay = !isDay`

After clicking the button1 on mainform it doesn't change the `isDay` boolen.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        
        mysubform1.DayModeButton.PerformClick();
        button1.Text = mysubform1.isDay.ToString();
       
    }
```

If I write this code it works, but I don't want to show and hide the form because it is not a good view for users.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        mysubform1.Visible=true;
        mysubform1.DayModeButton.PerformClick();
        button1.Text = mysubform1.isDay.ToString();
        mysubform1.Visible=false;
    }
```

Can anyone help me in performing a `Click` event in invisible forms?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use PerformClick in the first place? It is a bad habit to know something about the internas (a concrete button) on a different form and try to use that. I don't see why you need that. Give your subform a Method. Call that method if you need that and let your subform also call that method from the buttons click handler. And at best set all controls to private in your subform so you (no one) tries to call them directly.

Comment: @Ralf even better, if possible, avoid the need to have an invisible form an place the required logic in a class you can instantiate without the need to rely on a form, window messagges and so on. It depends on the need, but it's quite weird that you need a form to implement some logic

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `DayModeButton` is `Public` and not `Private`.

Comment: Button is public and perform click doesn't work properly. I created a method and call it now. Thanks for your helps.